# Why is one method working, yet another is not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails and creating my own personal to-do list. In my view I have the following:

```
<% @todo_list.todo_items.each do |todo_item| %>
      <% if todo_item.completed? %>
      <tr id="<%= dom_id(todo_item) %>">
        <td><%= todo_item.completed_at.strftime("%a %-m/%-d/%y ") %><%= link_to "Mark Complete", uncomplete_todo_list_todo_item_path(todo_item), method: :patch %></td>
        <td><%= todo_item.weeklypriority %></td>
```

In my controller I have:

```
  def complete
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
    @todo_item.update_attribute(:completed_at, Time.now)
    redirect_to todo_list_todo_items_path, notice: "Todo item marked as complete."
  end

  def uncomplete
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
    @todo_item.update_attribute(:completed_at, nil)
    redirect_to todo_list_todo_items_path, notice: "Todo item marked as uncomplete."
  end
```

When I use `complete_todo_list_todo_item_path(todo_item)` things work just dandy. When I use `uncomplete_todo_list_todo_item_path(todo_item)` I get

> undefined method `uncomplete_todo_list_todo_item_path' for #<#:0xb5509078>

When I change the complete method to do the same thing as the uncomplete method it works well. complete is not in any helper or set as a helper method, so I'm confused why uncomplete isn't working. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you post your routes too?

Comment: Unrelated, but good to know: "Incomplete" is the correct spelling for a non-completed object.

Comment: Thanks pyfl88 for pointing out the routes. That did the trick.

Comment: Wes: thanks for pointing that out as well. Not sure how I didn't realize that before hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to pyfl88 for asking about the routes. My routes looked like this:

```
Odot::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :todo_lists do
    resources :todo_items do
      member do
        patch :complete
      end
    end
  end
  root 'todo_lists#index'
```

So after adding *patch :uncomplete* to the routes it worked.